# How do I solve $a\sum_{i=0}^n k^i = c$ for $n$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there an analytical way of solving
$$
a\sum_{i=0}^n k^i = c
$$ for $n$? In words, how many terms will the sum consist of?

Comment: The sum is a geometric series. Do you know the formula for the sum of a geometric progression?

Comment: it's been a while, but indeed.

Comment: OK, so, what do you get when you use it?

Answer (score 2):

$$a\sum_{i=0}^nk^i$$

$$1+k+k^2+k^3+\cdots+k^n=\frac{c}{a}\tag{1}$$

If $k=1$, we have $n+1=\frac{c}{a}\implies n=\frac{c-a}{a}$.

If $k\ne1$ multiply by $k$ on both sides.

$$k+k^2+k^3+\cdots+k^{n+1}=\frac{kc}{a}\tag{2}$$

Subtracting $(1)$ from $(2)$,

$$k^{n+1}-1 =\frac{c}{a}(k-1)$$

$$k^{n+1}= \frac{c}{a}(k-1)+1=\frac{ck-c+a}{a}$$

$$n+1=\log_k\left(\frac{ck-c+a}{a}\right)$$

$$n=\log_k\left(\frac{ck-c+a}{a}\right)-1$$

Another interesting observation is that although the above formula is undefined for $k=1$, if we take the limit,

$$\lim_{k\to1}\left(\log_k\left(\frac{ck-c+a}{a}\right)-1\right)$$

This limit exists, and it evaluates to $\frac{c-a}{a}$ which happens to be the original solution for $n$ when $k=1$.

Can you justify *why*?

Comment: I'll accept your answer because of its explicit detail and if you tell me if the result $c=a(k^{n+1}-1)/(k-1)$ is the same as in my formula book where $c=a(1-k^{n})/(1-k)$, I cant seem to make the rearrangement, or i'm misunderstanding what that second formula refers to.

Comment: @TMOTTM yes it is the same. multiply by $-1$ in both the numerator and denominator. except the fact that in your book it says $k^n$, that should be $k^{n+1}$. (other answers agree with me)

Comment: Man i'm out of practice... I respectfully like to add that I'm pretty sure the book does not have a mistake there, since it's an absolute authoritative book.

Comment: @TMOTTM i respectfully disagree. being authoritative doesn't guarantee lack of typo. if you don't believe me, [WOLFRAM ALPHA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(k%5Ei)+from+i%3D0+to+n) is most definitely more authoritative than your book.

Comment: It is also more probable that the book has $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}$ instead of $\sum_{i=0}^{n}$ and the typo is yours.

Comment: Then would you agree that $a_0(1-k^{n+1})/(1-k) = a_1(1-k^n)/(1-k)$ where $a_1 = a_0 + a_0*k$?

Comment: @TMOTTM actually no. If you substitute, $a_1=a_0\cdot k$ you get $a_1(1-k^n)/(1-k) = a_0k(1-k^n)/(1-k) = a_0(\color{red}{k}-k^{n+1})/(1-k)$  close not same.

Comment: Then I'm not sure we agree, let me cite from the book (I'm still trusting it):
$k=a_{n+1}/a_n$ and $n$-th partial sum $s_n = a_1(1-k^n)/(1-k)$.

Comment: @TMOTTM okay sure. i'd like to see.

Answer (score 1):

Summing the GP,
$$a\frac{k^{n+1}-1}{k-1}=c$$
and so
$$k^n=\frac{c(k-1)+a}{ak}$$
from which you can find $n$.  If it turns out that $n$ is not a non-negative integer then it does not make sense for your question and there is no solution.

This assumes $k\ne1$; however if $k=1$ then we have
$$a(n+1)=c$$
which is even easier to solve.

Answer (score 0):

The sum is geometric:
$$
a \sum_{0 \le i \le n} k^i = a \frac{k^{n + 1} - 1}{k - 1} = c
$$
From here:
\begin{align}
k^{n + 1} &= 1 + \frac{c (k - 1)}{a} \\ 
n         &= {\ln \left( 1 + \frac{c (k - 1)}{a} \right) \over \ln k}-1
\end{align}